# Difference between local values and null_data_source for intermediate values on Terraform

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have a situation where I need to store some intermediate values so I can reuse them in other parts of the root module. I know about local values and I know about null_data_source except I do not know which one is the recommended option for holding re-usable values. Both descriptions look somewhat similar to me

*local values* (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html)

> Local values can be helpful to avoid repeating the same values or expressions multiple times in a >configuration, but if overused they can also make a configuration hard to read by future >maintainers by hiding the actual values used.

and *null_data_source* (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/data_source.html)

> The primary use-case for the null data source is to gather together collections of intermediate >values to re-use elsewhere in configuration:

So both appear to be a valid choice for this scenario.

Here is my example code

```
locals {
  my_string_A = "This is string A"
}

data "null_data_source" "my_string_B" {
  inputs = {
    my_string_B = "This is string B"
  }
}

output "my_output_a" {
  value = "${local.my_string_A}"
}

output "my_output_b" {
  value = "${data.null_data_source.my_string_B.outputs["my_string_B"]}"
}
```

Could you suggest on when to use the one over the other for holding intermediate values and what is the pros/cons of each approach?

Thank you

Comment: As per my understanding the null data source should be used when you have a collection of intermediate values and the locals to be used when you have a fairly simple values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `null_data_source` data source was introduced prior to the local values mechanism as an interim solution to meet that use-case before that capability became first-class in the language. It continues to be supported only for backward-compatibility with existing configurations using it.

All new configurations should use the Local Values mechanism instead. It's fully integrated into the Terraform language, supports values of any type (while `null_data_source` can support only strings), and has a much more concise/readable syntax.

Comment: I used `null_data_source` as a hack to wait for a file, as described [here](https://barneyparker.com/posts/installing-npm-dependencies-with-terraform/). I wouldn't know how to replicate that using locals.

Comment: I'd say `null_data_source` can enjoy another life today, as a way to add validation constraints for cases where they're not supported by the language yet (e.g. modules). Though, the builtin `terraform_data` resource can also work for this purpose if you don't mind an extra resource.

Comment: The `terraform_data` resource was introduced at least partly as a replacement for `null_data_source`: [https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-null/issues/86](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-null/issues/86)

Comment: `terraform_data` is closer to `null_resource` than it is to `null_data_source` in that it participates in the full managed resource lifecycle, rather than the data resource lifecycle. However, you _can_ use it for `null_data_source`-like things if you like. I expect local values will still work out better in most cases though, unless you specifically need something that participates as if it were a managed resource.